# Overlap with Mythology, how to draw the line?

Tags: discussion

The Mythology site has been around for some time and has a lot to offer. How can we best deal with the relation, and provide insight for the community which question to place where?

Maybe examples would be most illuminating?

Comment: Related (if not even duplicate): [What do we do with science fiction and fantasy?](http://meta.literature.stackexchange.com/q/4/50)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Mythology mod here! I have a couple of semi-relevant observations.

1. **Don't mind us.** Mythology's scope should not influence Literature's scope. It's fine if there's overlap, and obviously a question should not be closed on one site just because it's on-topic elsewhere.
2. **I don't think there will be a huge overlap in scope.** Mythological works are typically created and *believed* by those who create them. On Mythology, we view myths without thinking about whether or not they actually happened. Events in the Bible and Quran are as mythical as anything the ancient Sumerians believed in. I think that Literature is going to become a home for things that are explicitly fictional in nature.
3. **I hope there's some overlap in the userbase.** I've already seen several active Mythology users on Literature. You need to have the same kind of mind to be interested in either topic. I think we can help each other grow quite a lot. Mythology isn't graduated yet, so it doesn't have community promotion ads and can't add one for Literature, but I think [users there will quickly become aware](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34859583#34859583) of Literature's presence.

Answer (score 3):

The same way we deal with the SFF overlap:
https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6/16

and any potential future overlap